# going from one subject in PhD to another in Postdoc.

Tags: soft-question, career

Hi, my question is:

Is it acceptable to do a PhD in mathematics in a topic such as Number Theory and or Analysis and change subjects in postdoc to something different than these topics such as Geometry/Topology or something else?

I've looked on some pages of researchers in mathematics and most of them just continued their topic of dissertation after their graduation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not only is it desirable to broaden your research after completing your PhD studies. By some national funding agencies, such as the Swedish Research Council for example, this is actually a requirement to be elegible for their postdoctoral scholarships. You need to present a research plan that shows that you are are not "getting stuck" in old tracks.

Comment: Wasn't this already asked here? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/69937/changing-field-of-study-post-phd

Comment: @Johan Öinert: There's a difference between changing direction and changing subject completely.

Comment: @Jonny: You are right, and the answer to Alan's question "Is it acceptable...?" is of course "Yes!". The purpose of my comment was to demonstrate that change is usually considered to be a healthy and good thing.

Comment: @Johan Öinert: Absolutely.

Comment: One may change, but the main thing is "There should be motivation" for this. It is quite common that one area in maths is related to other, so having done some work in one area( which is perfectly fine in PhD) than shifting to other area, where you see the connection from previous work, then I would say, change is good and useful. Just changing area does not make sense, you need to justify, why?


Comment: Why all these answers as comments? (see also on meta: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1392/why-all-these-answers-as-comments/)

Comment: The question is too vague for me. There are no restrictions, and you are allowed at any time in your academic career to work on any subject you choose. You don't even have to work on math. You don't even have to do any work at all. You should just understand as well as you can the impact and risks of your actions and choices on your career as a mathematician, assuming that you want to pursue such a career.

Comment: Vote to close as too vague/not a real question as elaborated on by Deane Yang. In addition some general aspects were already discussed in the question linked to by Jonny Evans, so it also almost a duplicate. 

Comment: The question is very unclear. "Acceptable" presupposes some sort of value system of authorities who accept or not. Is it about your parents, your ex-advisor, your ex-sponsor, your beer pals, colleagues in your thesis area, or a prospective committee for a tenure track hiring in USA or China ?

Comment: Neeraj, justification of any path in intellectual pursuit is inner, and the typical requirements of some sponsor institution who get hysteric about something they do not understand about are not invalidating the inner turns. I do not understand "does not make sense". If somebody gets interested in something new, the interest itself generates large momentum. Instead I think that a restriction to what someone will live for does not make sense, and needs why ?

Comment: @Neeraj: finding an area of maths beautiful and deciding to do research in that area makes lots of sense and does not need justification. If such a switch preoccupies one completely and they leave their original field, so be it. 